# VRTK ignores IsTrigger

Tags: unity, collision-detection, virtual-reality

VRTK allow collision detection by adding the VRTK_HeadsetCollision, VRTK_BodyPhysics, VRTK_HeadsetFade and VRTK_HeadsetCollisionFade scripts into Unity.

This works so that in VR when I walk through a wall, the scene fades to black as expected.

However, I would also like to trigger events when I enter certain spaces in VR. Usually I would use a Unity BoxCollider with IsTrigger checked, but unfortunately, VRTK seems to ignore the IsTrigger value as it still fades to black when I enter the "zone".

How can I trigger a Unity event when the VR player enter's a zone with VRTK?